# Understanding how Cross-Platform App starts and uses xaml pages

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

(I have experience with MVC, WebForms, WinForms. I am getting started with Cross-Platform App projects.)

I created a Cross-Platform App project including Xamarin.Forms.
Visual Studio created 4 sub-projects:
"MyProject"
"MyProject".Android
"MyProject".iOS
"MyProject".UWP

I suppose that I actually have to develop most of my project in "MyProject" except for UI specifics things?

Then I have two questions:

- Where is it written in "MyProject".UWP that it has to display "MyProject"\MainPage.xaml?
- Why can't I view "MyProject"\MainPage.xaml in designer mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found both aswers:

> Where is it written in "MyProject".UWP that it has to display
>   "MyProject"\MainPage.xaml?

Somewhere in "MyProject".UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs is the line `MainPage = new MyProject.App();` and in "MyProject".UWP\App.xaml.cs is `MainPage = new MyProject.MainPage();`
(For those not used to work XAML files: the .cs code can be viewder click on the arrow left to the XAML file.)

> Why can't I view "MyProject"\MainPage.xaml in designer mode?

According to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer/
Possible answer: "There is not yet a visual designer for generating XAML in Xamarin.Forms applications, so all XAML must be hand-written."